# Specifying a region of the complex plane

Tags: complex, regions, language-design

I can use the following to specify a region of the complex plane.

```
R1=ImplicitRegion[1.0<=Norm[{a+1,b-1}]<=2.0,{a,b}];
RegionMember[R1,{0.5,1}]
```

It would be nice to do this in a way that I find more concise and readable. However, the following doesn't work.

```
R2 = ImplicitRegion[1.0 <= Norm[z - 1 + I] <= 2.0, {z}];
RegionMember[R2, 0.5 + I]
```

Is it true that Mathematica doesn't allow for a way to specify a region of the complex plane in terms of z?

Comment: Since `RegionDimension[R2]` yields `1`, your worst fears are confirmed. Complex numbers are not allowed. You'll have to split up real and imaginary parts.

Comment: Note that the [documentation of `ImplicitRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html) specifies that it "represents a region in R^n that satisfies the conditions *cond*". I don't think that it natively supports regions over complexes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is asking for functionality that is not supported given the constraints the OP is putting on the solution.